# QuickAction With ScrollView

Tags: android, basic4android

I am using Basic4Android as my programming language and I am trying to display the popup menu using the [AHQuickAction library](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/additional-libraries-classes-official-updates/14563-ahquickaction-library-nice-looking-popup-menus-13.html). (v1.01)

I am trying to make it when you tap on a label make it display the popup menu.

I am using the following code (which displays the popup menu)

```
Sub lblTest_Click
    Dim lbl As Label
    lbl = Sender
    ac1.show(Sender)
End Sub
```

however, it always displays the popup under the item I taped on.

As shown in the image below I taped on the last item in the list (Test 19) and the popup is displaying on top of the item I taped on and looks like I taped on Test 17.

is there a way to display the correct item I taped on ?

[image: http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/attachments/basic4android-updates-questions/15123d1356308413-ahquickaction-not-working-my-scrollview-wrong_item_selected.png]

I have attached the code as a zip so you can see what I mean and you might be able to tell me what I am missing. - [My Example Code](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/attachments/basic4android-updates-questions/15124d1356308813-ahquickaction-not-working-my-scrollview-quickaction_with_scrollview.zip)

In the example code, run the app on your device and tap on the label on the left in the app. You will find that it always displays under the item you tap on, where if there is space above the item you tapped on it never displays there.

Hope someone can help me out.